# How to solve using single quotes within double quotes within the $content = ' '

Tags: php, double-quotes, single-quotes

I am getting an error because of the single quotes that are within the double quotes, and everything is within the single quotes of the $content variable. How can this be solved please?

```
$content = '

setTimeout("finishAjax('usernameResult', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);

';
```

Comment: escape the quotes

Comment: $content = "setTimeout(\"finishAjax('usernameResult', 'escape(response)')\", 400)";

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for your reply.  However, it is still showing an error " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'usernameResult' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\fm-reg\register.php on line 105;"

Answer (score 0):

In order to put a single quote or double quote within a string literal, you have to escape it first. The escape character in PHP is the backslash (\).

```
$content = "setTimeout(\"finishAjax('usernameResult', '+escape(response)+')\", 400);";
```

Read more about escape characters [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).